# How to solve maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am facing maximum stored procedure, function trigger, or view nesting level exceeded. Here I want to find data on the base of fromdate and todate.

My problem arises that I'm trying to convert one date format to another. For example, I am converting this format 08-06-2020 00:00:00 to this 2020-06-08 00:00:00.000. The error is in Status = 1 and I am getting my data but with this error. I will be grateful if anybody can help me.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_GetRequest_DataListForViewPrint]
    @RequestNo VARCHAR(50),
    @FromDate varchar(50),
    @ToDate varchar(50),
    @Status varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQLStr varchar(8000)
    DECLARE @CurrentDate  Varchar(100) = GETDATE()

    IF (@RequestNo IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLStr = 'SELECT Id,RequestStatus, RequestNo,RequestDate From CYGNUX_Request_Header WHERE RequestNo='+''''+@RequestNo+'''';
    END
    ELSE      
        IF @Status = '1'
        BEGIN
            SET @SQLStr = 'select Id,RequestStatus,RequestDate,RequestNo from CYGNUX_Request_Header where RequestDate between '+CHAR(39)+  CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(datetime, @FromDate, 101), 103)  +CHAR(39)+ ' AND '+CHAR(39)+ CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(datetime, @ToDate, 101), 103) +CHAR(39);
        END

        IF @Status ='2'
        BEGIN
            SET @SQLStr = 'select Id,RequestStatus, RequestNo, RequestDate from CYGNUX_Request_Header where RequestDate>='+CHAR(39)+ CAST(DATEADD(day,-7,convert(varchar(100),@CurrentDate)) AS varchar(50))+CHAR(39);
        END

        IF @Status ='3'
        BEGIN
            SET @SQLStr = 'select Id,RequestStatus,RequestNo, RequestDate As Today from CYGNUX_Request_Header Where RequestDate='+CHAR(39)+  convert(varchar(50) , @CurrentDate)  +CHAR(39) ;
        END

        IF @Status ='4'
        BEGIN
            SET @SQLStr = 'select Id,RequestStatus, RequestNo,RequestDate  from CYGNUX_Request_Header WHERE RequestDate<=' +CHAR(39)+  convert(varchar(50) , @CurrentDate)  +CHAR(39);
        END 
    
        PRINT @SQLStr;
        EXEC(@SQLStr);
    END
```

Here is a screenshot of error which I am facing:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of error messages, post the actual text!

Comment: The fact that you have a nest that's hitting 32 iterations infers a design flaw. What is the *actual* problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: @SaritaPal . . . This code would not seem to have a nesting issue.  It must be in how you are calling the code.

Comment: A serious design flaw - including using dynamic SQL in a stored procedure making sure no syntax analysis tool finds anything when you do any rename. In 30 years I have never hit this limit - so you do something QUITE off. Definitely a design issue that is outside of the scope of a Q&A site.

Comment: It seems like CYGNUX_Request_Header must be a view with a lot of nested views inside it, nothing else here could reach a nesting limit. Also, the result of your @status=1 expression outputs columns in a different order from the others. That's probaly not what you want to do, is it? And as others have said, there's no need for dynamic SQL here.

Comment: there could also be a possibility that the function call is also added into the function definition (maybe you have altered the function with execution line in it), as there are multiple similar prints in the output which refers to multiple calls of the same function. Please check by openeing the code of the function in a separate window.

Comment: Comment out all in the Stored procedure and just have the SQL query for `@Status = '1'`, not assigned to the variable, instead, just the query, and let it be executed, when you call the stored procedure and tell what happened

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this code is causing your problem.  But could still be improved by eliminating the dynamic SQL.  Don't use dynamic SQL if it is not needed:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_GetRequest_DataListForViewPrint]
  @RequestNo VARCHAR(50),
  @FromDate DATE,
  @ToDate DATE,
  @Status varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN

    IF (@RequestNo IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SELECT Id, RequestStatus, RequestNo, RequestDate
        From CYGNUX_Request_Header
        WHERE RequestNo = @RequestNo;
    END;
    ELSE IF (@status = '1')
    BEGIN
        select Id, RequestStatus, RequestNo, RequestDate
        from CYGNUX_Request_Header 
        where RequestDate between @FromDate and ToDate;
    END;
    ELSE IF (@status = '2')
    BEGIN
        select Id, RequestStatus, RequestNo, RequestDate
        from CYGNUX_Request_Header 
        where RequestDate >= convert(date, getdate());
    END;
    . . .
END:
```

Answer (score 0):

when you created your store procedure, you build the exec in the next line for test, you executed together

Your problem is that the "EXEC sp_name" command is inside the stored procedure itself, so it keeps running in a loop, still that it's after of the end.

you can do:

create sp_name...
begin
...
end

**GO**

exec(sp_name)

that  will do the exec run separated

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).